# Jersey and Guice and nice JSON

Tags: java, json, serialization, jersey, guice

I have a project which uses Jersey 1.7, Guice 3.0 and has some JAXB annotated classes which are serialized through resources to XML and JSON. I'd like to configure the JSON output using a `ContextResolver` as suggested in several questions here on SO, as well as in the [Jersey User Guide](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e934). This involves creating a `JSONJAXBContext` like this:

```
public class JaxbResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {

    private final JAXBContext context;

    public JaxbResolver() throws Exception {
        this.ctx = new JSONJAXBContext(
            JSONConfiguration.
                natural().
                humanReadableFormatting(true).
                build(),
            Resource1.class, Resource2.class);
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

My problem is, that some of my resource classes have dependencies which are to be injected by Guice, like this:

```
public class DisplayConfigResource {
    private final ConfigRunner cr;

    @com.google.inject.Inject
    public DisplayConfigResource(ConfigRunner cr) {
        this.cr = cr;
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

If I remove my `JaxbResolver` from the game, everything works fine except that I have no control over the generated JSON (and the default is really weird, like removing the `[]`s from single-element collections, ...). So it seems it's common sense to plug a `ContextResolver` like mine into Jersey so I can tune the JSON to something I like. *But*

- the `JSONJAXBContext` class really likes to have no-arg constructors on the resources while
- my resources really like to have their dependecies injected in their constructors.

So my question is how to resolve this situation and have Jersey, Guice and JSON play nicely together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use Jackson instead of JAXB for JSON marshal/unmarshal. It uses the same `@XmlRootElement`, `@XmlType`, etc annotations and it produces a more standard output (and does not need those fancy `ContextResolver` natural configuration stuff).

First configure your web.xml:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>jersey</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Then add the `jersey-json` dependency in your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
  <version>1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I don't use Jersey in a Servlet container, so there is no `web.xml` to modify. But indeed that `POJOMappingFeature` looks very interesting. Do you have an idea how to set this using vanilla Jersey? (I'll have a look, too)

Comment: I've never heard about « vanilla » Jersey. What this is?

Comment: With "vanilla" I meant Jersey without Servlets.

Comment: @waldheinz I don't even know this was possible. Take a look at the documentation related to [POJOMappingFeature](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html#d4e901), you'll probably find how to use it the way you want.

Comment: Adding `getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE)` to the `ResourceConfig` implementation is what's needed for the non-servlet case. Thanks for bringing me on the right track!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I resolved it by creating custom JAXBContextResolver and manually specifying which classes are going to play nicely with json serialization:

```
@Provider
public class JAXBContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {

    private JAXBContext context;
    private Class<?>[] types = {DtoIdNazov.class, DtoLokalitaPoloha.class, DtoListRestauracie.class, DtoDetailRestauracia.class};

    public JAXBContextResolver() throws Exception {
        JSONConfiguration jsonConfiguration = JSONConfiguration.natural().build();
        this.context = new JSONJAXBContext(jsonConfiguration, types);
    }

    public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
        for (Class<?> type : types) {
            if (type == objectType) {
                return context;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very similar to the code I posted in my question. The problem I had with this is, that the `types` you give to the `JSONJAXBContext` need to have a no-arg constructor. But I'd like to have my dependencies injected with Guice.